# Barcode scanner app

Tags: ios, xcode6, barcode

So this isn't necessarily a code question, its more of a 'can it be done' question. I was wondering if there was a way to make an IOS app that could scan items in a store and read their barcode. It would then read what the item is and put it into a list. I've done some research on barcodes but I'm not sure if I can get that kind of information from them.

Comment: Yes you can scan barcodes - the trick is knowing what the barcode means - it is just a string of numbers. You need some database to tell you that that number is a box of cereal or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Scanning Barcodes of items shouldn't be a problem. There are several good libraries you can use for iOS and Android e.g.:

- ZBar (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/)
- MTBBarcodeScanner https://github.com/mikebuss/MTBBarcodeScanner

Otherwise the Question for Barcode Scanners was already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659380/free-barcode-scanner-sdk-for-ios-iphone

**//edit after some clarification:**

If your client has a database that shouldn't be a problem. The scenario is: All products have a barcode printed on them. The barcode represents an ID that your device will get when you scan it. After you scan it you can look up the product in their database with the help of the ID and show the product within the app. The only thing you need is being able to connect to their database (which shouldn't be a problem since they already use scanners).

Comment: So I have also found this: [link](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift) Would this gather the necessary information to build a list of products scanner?

Comment: As @Paulw11 mentioned above, barcodes are simply a string of numbers.  There is no centrally-maintained repository that translates a given barcode into a product or product description.  There are some databases that are accessible (a couple of examples are mentioned here - http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/562/does-there-exist-a-global-database-of-all-products-with-ean-13-barcodes).  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Steve Ok,,, so for example, if my client was a local Grocery store and they used scanners in their store to keep track of inventory, would there be a way to create an app for them using their data base?

Comment: @GlacierDevelopments Yes - their database would likely contain data that mapped products to barcodes.  When a new product comes in they would have to enter data corresponding to that product and also record its barcode.  The barcode would be translated into its string, and this string would be saved in the database as a key to the given product.